# laravel , error not find in migrate:rollback

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.1

in laravel 5.1 , vagrant, when I run

```
php artisan migrate
```

Migrated: 2017_04_20_205912_alter_3_discounts_table

but when I run

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

show this message :

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Class 'Alter3DiscountsTable' not found
```

I Have this class but I don't know why show this message!

any body can help?

** I run `composer dumpautoload` and show this :

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                               
File at "/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/CodeCoverage/Report/Node/Directory.php" does not exist, check your classmap definitions
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I find this:

```
$chcp.com 1252

=> Active code page: 1252
```

and now when run this :

```
$ composer dumpautoload
```

it's ok and show :

```
Generating autoload files
```